# Similar or different in meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In an FCE book I'm studying at the moment, it has been mentioned that the following sentences are similar in meaning, but I can't see the similarity! On the contrary, as a non-native speaker of English of course, I guess they must be different. What's your take on this?

> a)Money doesn't make you nearly as happy as you think.

> b)Money makes you a lot less happy than you think.

Answer (score 1):

> Money doesn't make you nearly as happy as you think.

In this sentence, we are looking at a situation of "nearly as happy".  If happy is "10", then nearly happy might be "7, 8, and 9".

The sentence says we are NOT at this level of happiness, and in fact, are at a lower level of happiness.

> Money makes you a lot less happy than you think.

In this sentence, we are talking about being less than "happy".  If happy is "10", then less is 9 or below... except that we are specifying "a lot less", which means that it couldn't be 7, 8, or 9 for sure, because that would be "nearly happy", not a "lot less" than happy.

As such, the two statements basically exclude the same possible levels of happiness, and are talking about roughly the same thing.

Granted, "a lot less" *could* exclude more than "not nearly", but in usage, "not nearly" is often an exaggeration, and actually means a lot more than the words strictly say.

They are roughly equivalent statements, and very similar in meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Actually, what I wasn't able to understand clearly was the difference between the phrases you've already mentioned here; "a lot less" and "not nearly".

Comment: @M.N The phrases are actually very similar in meaning.  **a lot less** means 'less, by a very large amount': *five is a lot less than three hundred.* 'not nearly' is an idiomatic phrase that means something like 'much less than' and is usually used when we're talking about a need or expectation.  *Don't worry, the problem is not nearly as bad as you think!*

Comment: @stangdon: That's much clearer now. Thanks a lot. +1

Answer (score 0):

> Money doesn't make you nearly as happy as you think.

It means that money won't make you even close to the happiness you think it would.

> Money makes you a lot less happy than you think

Instead, this sentence mean that money will make you a lot less happy than you think it would.

I (as a non-native speaker) would say that these two sentences are similar, but with a slightly different meaning